# Class ....TableMap not found while Spryker run console command

Tags: php, spryker

During any console command on Spryker console: Class ....TableMap not found in /data/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Runtime/Map/DatabaseMap.php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It caused when you switch branch -- sometimes you need to clean-up `src/Orm/Propel/generated-conf/loadDatabase.php` manually or even delete it and then run `console propel:install`.